# UNION types text and jsonb cannot be matched PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables on which I am trying to union all, one of the tables contains many jsonb columns.

I am doing this query,

```
  CREATE
  OR replace view datasets_dashboard AS WITH core AS
  (
    SELECT
      'twitch' AS tab_name,
      tw.id,
      tw.oid,
      tw.channel,
      tw.language,
      tw.mature,
      tw.partnered,
      tw.metadata,
      NULL AS alternate_text,
      NULL AS archived_url,
      NULL AS base_meme_name,
      NULL AS file_size,
      NULL AS md5_hash,
      NULL AS meme_id,
      NULL AS meme_page_url,
      NULL AS charge,
      NULL AS energy,
      NULL AS event,
      NULL AS invariant_mass,
      NULL AS run,
      NULL AS momemtum,
      NULL AS phi_angle,
      NULL AS pseudorapidity,
      NULL AS transverse_momemtum
    FROM
      public.twitch AS tw
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'memegen',
      meme.id,
      meme.oid,
      NULL AS channel,
      NULL AS language,
      NULL AS mature,
      NULL AS partnered,
      NULL AS metadata,
      meme.alternate_text,
      meme.archived_url,
      meme.base_meme_name,
      meme.file_size,
      meme.md5_hash,
      meme.meme_id,
      meme.meme_page_url,
      NULL AS charge,
      NULL AS energy,
      NULL AS event,
      NULL AS invariant_mass,
      NULL AS run,
      NULL AS momemtum,
      NULL AS phi_angle,
      NULL AS pseudorapidity,
      NULL AS transverse_momemtum
    FROM
      public.memegen AS meme
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'collision',
      collision.id,
      collision.oid,
      NULL AS channel,
      NULL AS language,
      NULL AS mature,
      NULL AS partnered,
      NULL AS metadata,
      NULL AS alternate_text,
      NULL AS archived_url,
      NULL AS base_meme_name,
      NULL AS file_size,
      NULL AS md5_hash,
      NULL AS meme_id,
      NULL AS meme_page_url,
      collision.charge,
      collision.energy,
      collision.event,
      collision.invariant_mass,
      collision.run,
      collision.momemtum,
      collision.phi_angle,
      collision.pseudorapidity,
      collision.transverse_momemtum
    FROM
      public.collision_electron AS collision
  )
  SELECT * FROM core;
```

from above these columns are jsonb

- tw.metadata
- collision.charge,
- collision.energy,
- collision.event,
- collision.invariant_mass,
- collision.run,
- collision.momemtum,
- collision.phi_angle,
- collision.pseudorapidity,
- collision.transverse_momemtum

I am trying to make them NULL for other tables where they wont exist but its throwing me such error as `types text and jsonb cannot be matched`. I have seen a few other answered question regarding this, But I am not sure where to use `CAST` in the query to make it work for jsonb type.

any help would be wonderful thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Cast NULL to jsonb as in:

```
NULL::jsonb AS base_meme_name,
```

Most (if not all) types can be casted to text which is why postgres assumes text (I assume:-) if no other information is given. One could argue that it should be possible to infer the correct type from the union, but I once again guess that it does not for practical reasons.